# PhoneGap SQL Database Update

Tags: sql, database, cordova

I have a PhoneGap application in which I need to update some .csv files for. The problem is my database is only populated once when the app loads from the store. I need to re-populate/parse my columns in the .csv files to update some data for the user. Currently my app loads and checks to see if the database is populated, but doesn't check for updates. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: `.csv files for` - for what? `loads from the store` - you mean GooglePlay? Any code extract?

Comment: My app sets up reference data for some pick lists in the application. The reference data comes from some .csv files which are loading the first time the app runs on your phone(sets up the tables/parses). Every time you open the app it checks to see if the database is populated and if it returns true it just moves on to the application. I need it to check if an .csv files have been updated since the last version.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table containing your database data version. On app load check if version inside app is latest. If not make a transactional updated where the last operation will be update of DB version to latest one.

Comment: So do something like db.changeVersion("1.0", "1.1") to change the version, then how would I do a transactional update? Some sort of UPDATE table_name function?

Comment: [http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#SQLTransaction](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#SQLTransaction).

Comment: I found this yesterday and it seems like the solution to this issue.http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/03/html5-web-sql-database-intro-to-versioning-and-migrations/